Unity InputSystemUIInputModule & EventSystem Loss of Data at OnDrag Behaviour
I am trying to drag an Icon game object. My project is 2D based, and the unity version is 2022.3 LTS
The implementation includes a draggable object that as it collides it gets destroyed and in its place another draggable icon game object is instantiated. The second might also collide to give its place to the first one (via destroy of current and instantiation of the first one).
So far I used the (1) old input manager, (2) the methods OnDrag and OnEndDrag of the IDragHandler and IEndDragHandler interfaces and the ExecuteEvents.Execute to transfer the OnDrag event onto the newely instantiated icon game object.
However, once I change to the new input system and I also change the EventSystem's module to the new InputSystemUIInputModule, the behavior is not working.
More specifically, the moment the dragged game object is being destroyed and the new one is instantiated the OnDrag stops; the new icon does not continue to follow the mouse. The user has to restart the drag with the newely created icon.
here is an example of the code I use on both the objects the I destroy and instantiate
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class DragIcon : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler
{
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D body;
    [SerializeField] private BoxCollider2D iconCollider;
    [SerializeField] private InterfaceIcon interfaceIconPrefab;

    
    private ParentObject parentObject;
    private Camera mainCamera;

    private void Awake()
    {
        mainCamera = Camera.main;
        parentObject = FindObjectOfType<ParentObject>();
    }

    private void ChangeIcons()
    {
        InterfaceIcon myInterfaceIcon = Instantiate
        (
            interfaceIconPrefab,
            transform.position,
            interfaceIconPrefab.transform.rotation,
            parentObject.transform
        );

        pointerEventData.pointerDrag = myInterfaceIcon.gameObject;

        ExecuteEvents.Execute(myInterfaceIcon.gameObject, pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.dragHandler);

        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData anEventData)
    {

    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData anEventData)
    {
        Vector2 myMousePosition = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Mouse.current.position.ReadValue());

        body.position = myMousePosition;

        pointerEventData = anEventData;
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData anEventData)
    {
        // some logic
    }

    private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        // some logic

        if (condition)
        {
            // some logic
        }
        else
        {
            ChangeIcons();
        }
    }
}

Is there some way that I can make this work?
Notice that if I did not had to make the destruction and instantiation of objects, and for instance I had to only drag a game object the OnDrag of the EventSystem would work just fine. But I think that because the game objects are being destroyed, the new input system and its module looses or resets drag information.
Thanks in advance
